# LinkedIn API Find posts by authors always return 404

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j, spring-social-linkedin

i'm trying to get all organization post with administrator accesstoken and organization URN.

1. i call the api: `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/post` [version:202306]
2. author params like this

   [image]
3. header like this

   [image]
4. return

   ```
   {
       "status": 404,
       "code": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
       "message": "No virtual resource found"
   }
   ```

comments:

1. the author param i have encode with %3A as separator. just like this: `urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A95737742`
2. organization id i have successfully confirmed by organization API, so i'm sure the organization id is right.

   [image]

i don't know the reason why always return 'resource not found' if the organization ID is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint is called "posts" not "post".
Besides that, everything looks correct to me.

Comment: thanks a lot, u resolve a big issue for me.